# Create a map/cache that will use objects generated by the default constructor for new keys

Tags: java, dictionary, guava

I am computing statistics grouped by an attribute. For each category of this attribute (given as `String`s) I get values which I want to aggregate.

For this, I need a map from category to `DescriptiveStatistics` (provided by `org.apache.commons.math.stat.descriptive`). In this map, I'd have to check if, for a given category, the corresponding `DescriptiveStatistics` have been created yet. **This check, and the creation of the new `DescriptiveStatistics`, should be done by the map.**

I tested Apache's `LazyMap`, but the non-genericity led me to Guava's `LoadingCache`. Something along these lines works for me:

```
LoadingCache<String, DescriptiveStatistics> groupedStats =
        CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
        .build(new CacheLoader<String, DescriptiveStatistics>() {
            @Override
            public DescriptiveStatistics load(String key) {
                return new DescriptiveStatistics();
            }
        });
```

Is there a less "wordy" solution? One that wouldn't require me to throw in an anonymous class just for instantiating objects?

Comment: I don't really see how you could be less wordy than this, at least without lambda expressions. It's just 3 lines of trivial code.

Comment: If no advanced concurrency handling, cache expiration and similar neat stuff is needed, then you can simply go with a HashMap. If you need real cache functionality, then there is no shorter code in Java to use Guava cache, only if you change to the Xtend language. Xtend is translated to Java in the background but it lets you get rid of the terse expressions.

Comment: @allprog: How do I specify the value factory in a `HashMap`?

Comment: @JBNizet: Perhaps there is a helper class which I have overlooked?

Comment: There isn't a helper class you've overlooked, there's no way to use a value factory in HashMap, and the Guava team recommends exactly the code that you've written.  (We generally tend to frown on e.g. reflectively invoking default constructors.)

Comment: You can always simply extend HashMap and override the get method. However, this is a hack, for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your original code is exactly the code the Guava team would like you to write.

We tend to avoid reflection (except, naturally, in `com.google.common.reflect`).  It tends to be fragile and lose the benefits of compile-time checking -- if a particular class doesn't *have* a public no-arg constructor, and you used `clazz.newInstance()`, you wouldn't find that out until runtime.  Writing the direct implementation might cost you a line or two, but we consider the benefits worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I you want to have less wordy solution create a class that you will used for your cache.

As someone design API can not always make happy every one. Guava cache is very flexiple and adaptable. And the additional few code of line should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is my idea of reducing wordiness in user code: A class `Creator<T>` that does just what it says.

```
LoadingCache<String, SummaryStatistics> groupedStats =
    CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build(
        CacheLoader.from(Creators.of(SummaryStatistics.class)));
```

I was wondering if such a beast exists; I couldn't find it in the classes implementing `Supplier<T>`. Here's a possible implementation, all classes in the same package:

```
import com.google.common.base.Supplier;

public class Creator<T> implements Supplier<T> {

    private Class<T> class1;

    Creator(Class<T> class1) {
        this.class1 = class1;
    }

    @Override
    public T get() {
        try {
            return class1.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Cannot instantiate object of type "
                        + class1.getCanonicalName(),
                    e);
        }
    }

}

public class Creators {
    public static <T> Creator<T> of(Class<T> class1) {
        return new Creator<T>(class1);
    }
}
```

Of course this could be generalized to using constructors with arguments.

Comment: We don't provide such a thing in Guava partially because we're not especially fond of reflection.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: Thank you. Are the reasons for this documented somewhere? Can you think of an implementation that wouldn't use reflection?

Comment: An implementation that wouldn't use reflection would be exactly the implementation you wrote in the original question.  But wrt the reasons for this -- we dislike the fragility of reflection, the lack of compile-time checking, and all of the wonderful things you get if you write the straightforward implementation.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: Would you care to post all of this as an answer, for further reference?